# I have a problem with the command "look at" in three js code

Tags: javascript, three.js

Good afternoon, I have a problem in "three" js with the "look at" command. The point is that an object by default follows another object only by its axis Z. No matter how I tried, it doesn't turn the other side
here is my code

```
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:Colors.green,wireframe:true});
var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry,boxMaterial);
scene.add(boxMesh);

var SphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,10,10);
var SphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:Colors.red,wireframe:true});
var Sphere = new THREE.Mesh(SphereGeometry,SphereMaterial);
Sphere.position.z=-100;
scene.add(Sphere);


var angle = 0;



    function loop() {
    
    controls.update();
    Sphere.position.x+=Math.cos(angle);
    boxMesh.lookAt(Sphere.position);
    angle+=Math.PI/180
     renderer.render(scene,camera);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){loop();});
    
    

    
}
loop();
```

}
I want the other side of the cube to follow the sphere
Problem is here

```
boxMesh.lookAt(Sphere.position);
```

Comment: Try `var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10); boxGeometry.rotateY( Math.PI );`

Comment: This works, but only with simple shapes. And I want to rotate a container with many shapes